# How to pass a tRPC procedure to component and type correctly

Tags: typescript, react-query, trpc.io

I'm trying to pass a tRPC v10 query procedure to a custom table component and type it correctly. Below is a simplified code snippet of what I'm trying to achieve.

I tried typing it as a `QueryProcedure<any>` but then I get `Property 'useInfiniteQuery' does not exist on type 'QueryProcedure<any>'`. That's probably because tRPC infers the `useInfiniteQuery` based on the presence of the `cursor` attribute. My TypeScript knowledge is too limited to go any further. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
type Props<T extends object> = {
  columns: ColumnsType<T>;
  defaultSortField: string;
  dataQuery: any; // <-- how to type this?
};

const CustomTable = <T extends object>(props: Props<T>) => {
    const res = props.dataQuery.useInfiniteQuery({
        limit: 10,
    });

    ...
}

<CustomTable<Foo>
    columns={columns}
    dataQuery={trpc.foo.getFoos}
    defaultSortField="foobar"
/>
```

Example tRPC router

```
const fooRouter = t.router({
  getFoos: t.procedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        limit: z.number().min(1).max(100),
        cursor: z.number(),
      }),
    )
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { limit, cursor } = input;
      const queryRes = ctx.prisma.foo.findMany({
        take: limit + 1,
        cursor: { Id: cursor },
      });

      let nextCursor: typeof cursor;
      if (queryRes.length > limit) {
          const nextRes = queryRes.pop();
          nextCursor = nextRes.Id;
      }

      return {
          items: queryRes,
          nextCursor,
      };
    }),
});
```

Comment: AFAIK useInfiniteQuery is a function, not a method. So what is `dataQuery`? You ask us what the type should be, but aren't showing us any of the code?

Comment: `dataQuery` is a tRPC query procedure. I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: Removed the example again. It does not offer any value. One has to know tRPC to provide help.

Comment: "One has to know tRPC to provide help" yes I don't disagree. But I rolled back your removal of the example. From the help center code samples should ["Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It may be obvious to *you* that dataQuery is a React Query result, but it will not necessarily be obvious to someone else, even someone else who knows React Query.

Comment: I don’t appreciate you also rolling back my simplified and reworked code sample. I agree. Providing reproducible code is important. But there are levels to this. I need to stop somewhere, otherwise, I can post my entire app. I feel like it is enough without the router code.

Comment: The router example also doesn’t tell you that it‘s a react query result.